# Android UI fragments. Changing fragment due to button push

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to open a new fragment based on a button push in a previous fragment. What's the best way to implement this?

I'm curious if it's Activity -> .add + .commit original fragment - > from that fragment.java .replace new fragment?

Or do I need to pass an intent back up to the activity and create/replace that fragment from the activity?

So summarize: Activity A - > Fragment 1 - > Fragment 2.

I'm also slightly confused on what things I [need] to @Override. I think only onCreate and onCreateView [within each fragment]?
I'm only looking for high-level here; I want to struggle through the code myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments are generally unaware of their host so I would use the standard callback method to call your activity and ask it to switch fragments.

Create an interface

Have your activity implement the interface.

Cast the getActivity() call to your interface.

Call the interface method.

This is much cleaner than casting the host activity and calling methods on it. It also means your fragment can be hosted in different activities with no cast errors.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Where do I implement/create the interface? In my fragment?

Comment: I gave a link with full instructions

Comment: I guess my problem is what do I pass with my listener? Should I create the fragment "in" my fragment and pass that back? Or should I pass back the whole view?

Comment: Nevermind; figured it out; pass back the View from my fragment to the Activity and have a switch taking the different button views and creating a fragment within the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast getActivity like:

```
((MyActivity) getActivity())
```

And then if you have that, you can call a method in yout activity:

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragments(Object... params);
```

And inside the method you should do the replace fragment process.

So simply you have the right idea.